# When an odd polynomial is a one-one map on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: polynomials, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f(x)=c_1x+c_3x^3+c_5x^5+\cdots+c_{2m+1}x^{2m+1}$, $c_1,c_3,c_5,\ldots,c_{2m+1} \in \mathbb{R}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$,
namely, $f$ is an odd polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$.

> When such a polynomial is a one-one map on $\mathbb{R}$?
>   Is it always one-one?

Example:

$f(x)=x+x^3$. If $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$a+a^3=b+b^3$, so $(a-b)+(a^3-b^3)=0$,
and then, $(a-b)(1+(a^2+ab+b^2))=0$.

Therefore, $a-b=0$ or $1+(a^2+ab+b^2)=0$.
In the first case $a=b$ and we are done, while in the second case,
the discriminant is $-4-3a^2 < 0$, so there are no $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $1+(a^2+ab+b^2)=0$.

I guess that a general solution should be similar to the special case of the example: If 
$c_1a+c_3a^3+c_5a^5+\cdots+c_{2m+1}a^{2m+1}=c_1b+c_3b^3+c_5b^5+\cdots+c_{2m+1}b^{2m+1}$, then $(a-b)(c_1+c_3(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)+\cdots)=0$,
so (first case) $a-b=0$ and we are done, or (second case) $c_1+c_3(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)+\cdots=0$, which I am not sure I know how to show that it is necessarily non-zero (it is an even polynomial).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but $x^3-x$  factors as $(x+1)x(x-1)$, so has three distinct real roots, so is not one-to-one, which seems to answer your question about whether all odd polynomials are one-to-one.

Comment: It's easy to draw a non-injective cubic ("up-down-up"), and I think $x^3-x$ is an example of such a non-injective cubic.

Comment: Truly, I originally considered $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, but then there are complex solutions, so $f$ is not one-one. Is there any chance to say something on the coefficients $c_1,c_3,\ldots,c_{2m+1}$ which will guarantee that $f$ is one-one?

Comment: I see that Mihail has mentioned that if all the (real) coefficients are of the same sign, then $f$ is one-one.

Comment: @MJD, thanks. I think you understood the question, but I was not clear enough, having several thoughts in mind, not writing them clear enough.  And thanks for Noah Schweber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true in general. It is 1-1 iff its derivative never changes the sign. Counterexamples would be any of the antiderivatives of $g(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$. One the other hand, one of the sufficient conditions would be to have all of the coefficients of the same sign. Also requiring the coefficient of the top power monomial to be large(or small) enough with respect to other coefficients and to have the same sign as the constant term would be sufficient. Here the idea is the following: We know that if we go away from zero then any polynomial will be 1-1. Therefore forcing the polynomial to speed up around zero too(to make it 1-1)  requires some dancing with the coefficient of the top power monomial.

The question of positivity of arbitrary polynomial is a difficult one and is the subject of real algebraic geometry. I suspect that even in the case of having only odd powers of monomials it is not an easy question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that your answer is more or less what I was looking for (I knew the argument with the derivatives. Your sufficient conditions are nice).

Comment: Please, is there any chance that your second sufficient condition (about the leading coefficient) is also relevant if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$? Perhaps I should ask this in a new question with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}$, looking for sufficient conditions guaranteeing $f$ being one-one. (Perhaps one should consider the absolute values of the coefficients? I am not sure if this is relevant).

Comment: `It is 1-1 iff its derivative is always positive (or negative)` This could be better worded as "*its derivative never changes sign*". For example, $\,x^3\,$ *is* a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ even though its derivative is not (strictly) positive on  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @dvix thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @Mihail, please, is your second sufficient condition valid? It seems to contradict Peter Green answer, more precisely his argument: ''If the first and last non-zero coefficients have different signs then the function is not one to one because for sufficiently large x the largest power dominates and for sufficiently small x the smallest (possibly zero) power dominates.

Comment: @user237522 i'm sorry and thank you. I modified it a little, so that now it sounds correct to me.

Comment: @Mihail, thank you! BTW I searched for 'positive polynomials' and indeed determining positiveness of odd real polynomials seems a difficult question...

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer in response to the discussion in the comments on Peter Green's answer.

**Claim:** A non-constant polynomial function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one if and only if either $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ or $f'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$.

*Proof:* Since $f'$ is a nonzero polynomial (this is where we use the fact that $f$ is nonconstant), it has only finitely many zeros $z_1<\dots<z_n$. And $f'$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative on each interval $(-\infty,z_1)$, $(z_1,z_2)$, $\dots$, $(z_{n-1},z_n)$, $(z_n,\infty)$.

If $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on each of these intervals. It follows by continuity that $f$ is strictly increasing everywhere (e.g. $f(z_i) = \text{sup}\{f(x)\mid x\in (z_{i-1},z_i)\} > f(y)$ for all $y\in (z_{i-1},z_i)$). In particular, it is one-to-one. The case $f'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$ is similar.

Conversely, suppose $f'$ is positive on some of these intervals and negative on others. Then there is some $z_i$ such that the sign of $f'$ is different on the intervals immediately to the left and right of $z_i$. Say $f'$ is positive on $(z_{i-1},z_i)$ and negative on $(z_i,z_{i+1})$, setting $z_0 = -\infty$ in case $i = 1$ and $z_{n+1} = \infty$ in case $i = n$. Then $f$ has a local maximum at $z_i$, which implies it is not one-to-one (in the other case, $f$ has a local mininum instead).

To argue this carefully, we can pick points $z_{i-1}<x<z_i<y<z_{i+1}$ in these intervals. Then $f(x) < f(z_i)$ since $f$ is increasing on $(z_{i-1},z_i)$ and $f(y)<f(z_i)$ since $f$ is decreasing on $(z_i,z_{i+1})$. If $f(x)<f(y)<f(z_i)$ (the other case is similar), then by the intermediate value theorem there is some $x<x'<z_i$ such that $f(x') = f(y)$. This shows that $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you very much! You and Peter Green have not used my assumption that $f$ is an odd polynomial, so it has the advantage of being applied in other situations (I do not know which answer to accept, your answer or Mihail's answer..)

Comment: I think you have some missing prime symbols in your proof.

Comment: @PeterGreen Yes, thanks - I think I've fixed them all.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I'm not 100% sure but I believe</s>(another answer has now provided a proof) a non-constant polynomial forms a 1:1 mapping from the reals to the reals if and only if one of the following is true.

$$\frac{df}{dx}\ge 0 \space\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $$

$$\frac{df}{dx}\le 0 \space\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $$

Lets look a bit at the case presented in your question of polynomials with only odd powers of $x$ (note: I believe this is not the normal definition of "odd polynomial").

$\frac{df}{dx}=c_1+c_33x^2+c_55x^4+\cdots+c_{2m+1}(2m+1)x^{2m}$

The derivative only contains even powers. So the sign of each term in the derivative is always either zero or the same as the sign of it's coefficient.

- If all coefficients have the same sign then the function is one to one.
- If the first and last non-zero coefficients have different signs then the function is not one to one because for sufficiently large $x$ the largest power dominates and for sufficiently small $x$ the smallest (possibly zero) power dominates.

Of course that leaves unsolved that case were the first and last coefficients have the same sign but the intermediate coefficients have different signs.

Comment: That's true for any smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $>$ and $<0$? Or perhaps it is enough $\geq 0$ $\leq 0$, since when zero it is only suspected to be minimum or maximum, but perhas it is not either one (if the second derivative vanishes).

Comment: 1.Both cases are accepted as long as the case holds on the whole line. 
2. It is neither, just a critical point similar to $x^3$ around zero.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, thanks. Can you please give a reference to your claim? (you meant the condition of Peter Green).

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but I can give you a proof instead. Let me write it as a new answer.

Comment: I have extended my answer to look a bit more at the case of a polynomial with only odd powers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, ti is not always one-to-one.

Consider the following  odd polynomial

$$P(x)=x(x-5)(x-10)= x^3-15x^2+50x$$

$$ P(0)=P(5)=P(10)=0$$

It is  not one-to-one.

However, a function will be one-to-one if it's derivative is always positive or always negative.