# When an odd polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ is a one-one map on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f(x)=c_1x+c_3x^3+c_5x^5+\cdots+c_{2m+1}x^{2m+1}$, $c_1,c_3,c_5,\ldots,c_{2m+1} \in \mathbb{C}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$,
namely, $f$ is an odd polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$.

> When such a polynomial is a one-one map on $\mathbb{C}$?

(What can be said about the coefficients of $f$? Are their absolute values of the same sign? What about the derivative of $f$? is it relevant at all?).

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687041/when-an-odd-polynomial-is-a-one-one-map-on-mathbbr-always/2687055#2687055) we deal with $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$.

Clearly, in my current question $f$ is not always one-one, for example:
$f(x)=x+x^3$. If $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$a+a^3=b+b^3$, so $(a-b)+(a^3-b^3)=0$,
and then, $(a-b)(1+(a^2+ab+b^2))=0$.

Therefore, $a-b=0$ or $1+(a^2+ab+b^2)=0$.
In the first case $a=b$, but in the second case,
there are two families of solutions with $b \neq a$,
so $f$ is not one-one.

**Remark:**
Observe that such $f$ was one-one on $\mathbb{R}$ (= its derivative is positive 
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: What do you know about the number of (complex) roots of $\,f(x) = c\,$ for an arbitrary $\,c \in \mathbb{C}\,$?

Comment: So there is no hope to obtain that $f$ is one-one? (since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so there is always a solution for the right hand equation thinking about $b$ as a variable and the equation is over $\mathbb{C}(a)$).

Comment: $f$ is never an injection if $m \ge 1$.

Comment: Not only are no polynomials of degree $>1$ one-to-one on $\mathbb C$, no entire functions except polynomials of degree $1$ are one-to-one on $\mathbb C$.  This
follows from the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one to one if the degree is $1$ otherwise $f(x)=c$ has more than one root for some values of $c$. If $m=deg f>0$, $f$ has $m$ roots with multiplicity counted, if you have two root distincts, done if all the root are equal, $f=(X-a)^m$ and $f(x)=c, c\neq a$ has distinct roots, since if $u$ is a root of $f(x)=c$, $u\neq a$ and $f'(u)\neq 0$ this implies that $u$ is a simple root.